# Windows Service Error of System.OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I've created windows service which runs in every 1.5 hrs of time 24x7 days. This service is to consume the API, fetch the records from api and save the records on our database which is MS Dynamics in my case. Problem is that it starts giving error stating "Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 8388608 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low." after running for 2-3 days. Then I've to restart the service to make it work again.

Given is my code.Please check.

```
//This is called when connection with database is succesfully created.
public void getAirpayData()
{

        try
        {
            Airpay airpayVerify = new Airpay();

            QueryExpression getPaymentGatewayTransaction = new QueryExpression("new_paymentgatewaytransaction");
            var filter1 = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.Or);
            filter1.AddCondition("new_transactionstatus", ConditionOperator.Null);
            filter1.AddCondition("new_transactionstatus", ConditionOperator.Equal, 211);//Transaction In Process
            filter1.AddCondition("new_transactionstatus", ConditionOperator.Equal, 403);//INCOMPLETE
            filter1.AddCondition("new_transactionstatus", ConditionOperator.Equal, 401);//dropped
            filter1.AddCondition("new_transactionstatus", ConditionOperator.Equal, 405);//bounced
            var filter2 = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
            filter2.AddCondition("createdon", ConditionOperator.GreaterEqual, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15));// Runs for past 15 days transaction
            getPaymentGatewayTransaction.Criteria.AddFilter(filter1);
            getPaymentGatewayTransaction.Criteria.AddFilter(filter2);
            getPaymentGatewayTransaction.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
            EntityCollection PaymentGatewayTransactionCollection = service.RetrieveMultiple(getPaymentGatewayTransaction);


            if (PaymentGatewayTransactionCollection != null && PaymentGatewayTransactionCollection.Entities.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Entity paymentGateway in PaymentGatewayTransactionCollection.Entities)
                {
                    airpayVerify.merchant_txnId = paymentGateway.Contains("new_name") ? paymentGateway.GetAttributeValue<string>("new_name") : "NA";
                    if (airpayVerify.merchant_txnId != "NA")
                    {
                        var client = new RestClient("https://payments.airpay.co.in/order/verify.php");
                        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                        //request.AddHeader("postman-token", "03b48494-0184-39ed-8e52-a025a2adccfd");
                        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
                        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                        request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "mercid=94&merchant_txnId=" + airpayVerify.merchant_txnId + "&privatekey=526c7c9b9a40d564888bdcec3040906d3be3ebc1f3a81ab02e90", ParameterType.RequestBody);

                        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TRANSACTION), new XmlRootAttribute("TRANSACTION"));

                        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(response.Content.Replace("<![CDATA[", "").Replace("]]>", "").Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>", "").Replace("<RESPONSE>", "").Replace("</RESPONSE>", ""));

                        TRANSACTION productList = (TRANSACTION)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);

                        UpdateCRMLog(productList);
                    }
                }
            }
            //  Library.WriteErrorLog("getAirpayDataEnd");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Library.WriteErrorLog(ex.Message);
        }





    }

    public void UpdateCRMLog(TRANSACTION productList)
    {
        try
        {
            //  Library.WriteErrorLog("UpdateCRMStart");
            EntityCollection paymentGatewayTransaction = op.QueryExpression("new_paymentgatewaytransaction", productList.TRANSACTIONID, "new_name", false, service);
            //    EntityCollection paymentGatewayTransaction = Global.GetEntityCollection(service, "new_paymentgatewaytransaction", productList.TRANSACTIONID, string.Empty, false, false, false, "new_name", string.Empty);
            if (paymentGatewayTransaction != null && paymentGatewayTransaction.Entities.Count > 0)
            {
                if (!paymentGatewayTransaction.Entities[0].Contains("new_paymentgatewayresponsestring"))
                {
                    paymentGatewayTransaction.Entities[0]["new_paymentgatewayresponsestring"] = Convert.ToString(productList.APTRANSACTIONID);
                }
                paymentGatewayTransaction.Entities[0]["new_transactiontype"] = Convert.ToString(productList.TRANSACTIONTYPE);
                paymentGatewayTransaction.Entities[0]["new_transactionstatus"] = Convert.ToString(productList.TRANSACTIONSTATUS);
                paymentGatewayTransaction.Entities[0]["new_transactionpaymentstatus"] = Convert.ToString(productList.TRANSACTIONPAYMENTSTATUS);
                paymentGatewayTransaction.Entities[0]["new_responsestatus"] = Convert.ToString(productList.TRANSACTIONPAYMENTSTATUS);
                paymentGatewayTransaction.Entities[0]["new_chmod"] = Convert.ToString(productList.CHMOD);
                if (productList.SURCHARGE == "")
                {
                    productList.SURCHARGE = "0.00";
                }
                decimal paidAmountIncludingSurcharge = Convert.ToDecimal(productList.BILLEDAMOUNT) + Convert.ToDecimal(productList.SURCHARGE);
                paymentGatewayTransaction.Entities[0]["new_paymentgatewayamount"] = Convert.ToString(paidAmountIncludingSurcharge);
                paymentGatewayTransaction.Entities[0]["new_paidamount"] = Convert.ToString(productList.AMOUNT);
                paymentGatewayTransaction.Entities[0]["new_bankname"] = Convert.ToString(productList.BANKNAME);
                paymentGatewayTransaction.Entities[0]["new_customername"] = Convert.ToString(productList.CUSTOMER);
                paymentGatewayTransaction.Entities[0]["new_currencycode"] = Convert.ToString(productList.CURRENCYCODE);
                paymentGatewayTransaction.Entities[0]["new_risk"] = Convert.ToString(productList.RISK);
                paymentGatewayTransaction.Entities[0]["new_transactiontime"] = Convert.ToString(productList.TRANSACTIONTIME);
                string _transactionTime = Convert.ToString(productList.TRANSACTIONTIME);
                string[] formats = { "M/d/yyyy", "d/M/yyyy", "M-d-yyyy", "d-M-yyyy", "d-MMM-yy", "d-MMMM-yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" };
                DateTime fromdate = DateTime.MinValue;
                DateTime.TryParseExact(_transactionTime, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out fromdate);
                paymentGatewayTransaction.Entities[0]["new_paymenttransactiondate"] = fromdate;
                service.Update(paymentGatewayTransaction.Entities[0]);
                //   Library.WriteErrorLog("UpdateCRMEnd");
            }
            //      Library.WriteErrorLog("UpdateCRMEnd1");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Library.WriteErrorLog(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: First: you need to add some "using" statements or make sure you're cleaning up in a try/finally or something. But the error message you're posting is unlike I've ever seen from the .Net framework, so I assume it to originate from ms dynamics.

Comment: It looks like you may have left some private information in your post (keys, merchantids) you may want to edit them out and ping a mod to fix the history

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I've used some random numbers there instead of orignal ones. So no problem with that.